# Javascript - I created a blob from a string, how do I get the string back out?

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I have a string that I called Blob() on:

```
var mystring = "Hello World!";
var myblob = new Blob([mystring], {
    type: 'text/plain'
});
mystring = "";
```

How do I get the string back out?

```
function getBlobData(blob) {
    // Not sure what code to put here
}
alert(getBlobData(myblob)); // should alert "Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In order to extract data from a Blob, you need a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
    alert(reader.result);
}
reader.readAsText(blob);
```

Comment: So how can I wrap that in a function and have it return the result?

Comment: @Joey see question [Call An Asynchronous Javascript Function Synchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously)

Comment: Well, I got it to wrap in a function. But for some reason it only works the second time I try to access it: http://jsfiddle.net/vMrF5/

Comment: @Joey That's because of a race conditions. The asynchronous loading happens in the background. The first time it's not loaded yet, the second time it might already be. However, do not rely on that! That's undefined behavior which will vary from execution to execution. You have absolutely no way to tell how long loading will take.

Comment: In case someone else wants to wrap this in a function, see my answer below.

Answer (score 45):

@joey asked how to wrap @philipp's answer in a function, so here's a solution that does that in modern Javascript (thanks @Endless):

```
const text = await new Response(blob).text()
```

Comment: if you want it as a promise just do `const text = await new Repsponse(blob).text()`

Answer (score 28):

If the browser supports it, you could go via a blob *URI* and *XMLHttpRequest* it

```
function blobToString(b) {
    var u, x;
    u = URL.createObjectURL(b);
    x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('GET', u, false); // although sync, you're not fetching over internet
    x.send();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(u);
    return x.responseText;
}
```

Then

```
var b = new Blob(['hello world']);
blobToString(b); // "hello world"
```

Comment: it's a bit hacky, isn't there a less hacky way to do it?

Comment: This works, but chrome 76 now warns of deprecation `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Comment: Yes it's working with error in FireFox '85.0.2 (64-bit)' `XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: blob:http://localhost:4200/40be6ace-691c-43a2-b208-824a0d0a933
Line Number 1, Column 1` for my 'Angular 6' app.
To solve this need to add type, `const b = new Blob(['hello world'], { type: 'text/plain' });`

Answer (score 24):

You could use the [`blob.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) method.

```js
blob.text().then(text => {
  let blobText = text
})
```

It will return the content of the blob in UTF-8 encoding.
Note that it has to be in an async.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
var mystring = "Hello World!";
var myblob = new Blob([mystring], {
    type: 'text/plain'
});
mystring = "";
outurl = URL.createObjectURL(myblob);
fetch(outurl)
.then(res => res.text())
.then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})

//'Hello World'
```

Comment: Haven't  tried this, but seems legit according to https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Body/blob and is more straight than the XMLHttpRequest answer of Paul S.

Comment: Thanks. (I am very new and have not even gotten an upvote until now)