# Cant load blob as text on js

Tags: javascript, blob, filereader

So, I have a blob as a txt inside a zip. I can access the txt file but I cant open it. I've installed by npm the FileReader and tried something that I saw here on stackoverflow `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024460/javascript-i-created-a-blob-from-a-string-how-do-i-get-the-string-back-out`, but I get nothing neither alerts or logs.

```
convertInText = (blob) => {

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(blob, "ANSI");
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            console.log(reader.result);
        };

    };
```

Also imported FileReader and all but no result.

Comment: This isn't a valid code sample.  Where is blob defined, no link to what you tried on stack, I don't see how you expect to see anything in a log?  Where is the log statement.. You need some more samples here.

Comment: @DylanWright that is what I used from stack, updated with the link and the method. Alert/console.log, was just to tell that I tried both. What would be the purpose of having both? Thought it was obvious that would go to where the alert is.

Comment: What do you mean by "I installed by NPM FileReader"?  When you look at the listed Stack Question you provided a link to there is a link to MDN FileReader API..  not a npm package.  There is also a JSFiddle in the comment of the answer, http://jsfiddle.net/dnmSR/ with a working sample

Comment: If you're still having an issue your file may have some kind of read/write permission on it or possible it's open somewhere else by another process.

Comment: Oh my bad, was using the URL instead of the object Blob itself, figured that out using that jsfiddle. Thanks!

Comment: No problem and good luck