# To call an asynchronous function synchronously in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, call

```
 we are trying to change some calls in the application from sync to async then i read the post
```

"[Call An Asynchronous Javascript Function Synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously)"
so when i call the callThis() I am getting the output as:
   "Success"
   "failure"
but I need the output as 
   "Success"
   "KATE success"

Can you guys suggest me a solution for this, not the callback or timeout but still an efficient technique when changed from sync to async

```
function callThis()
{
    if(kate())
    {
      console.log("KATE success")
    }
 else
  {
   console.log("failure")
  }
}
function kate()
{
  $.ajax({
        url: "www.google.com" (http://www.google.com),
        type: 'get',
        async: true,
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("FAIL!!!");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution isn't to call it synchronously, but to work *with* the asynchronous nature of ajax

```
function callThis() {
    kate().done(function(result) {
        if ( result ) {
            console.log("KATE success")
        } else {
            console.log("failure")
        }
    }).fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

function kate() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "www.google.com",
        type: 'get',
        async: true,
        timeout: 10000
    });
}
```

note that getting `google.com` will fail due to the same-origin policy

Comment: I don't want to change the function kate() because everyone is using it so If I change that I need to change the whole thing , so can we use promise:done or then or any other solution which helps me

Comment: Nope, it simpy can't be done without changing that function, either by returning a promise, using a callback or adding async false, which you shouldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the promise interface that jQuery returns (`.done`), like this:

```
function callThis() {
    kate().done(function(result) {
        if ( result ) {
            console.log("KATE success")
        } else {
            console.log("failure")
        }
    }).fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    console.log("KATE SPADE")
}

function kate() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "www.google.com",
        type: 'get',
        async: true,
        timeout: 10000
    });
}
```

Even the asynchronous nature of ajax is now taken into account, I am still getting the output as:

> KATE SPADE \n
>
> KATE success

Comment: I need the output to be reverse i.e KATE success and KATE SPADE