# In angular function not waiting to complete first function execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my function didnt wait to complete earlier function execution and it is completing.

I have my code is that i am doing some thing wrong:

```
$scope.abc1 = function(){
 var arrayJson = [{'name':'max','age':'12'},{'name':'tax','age':'16'}]
 for(var i=0; i<arratJson.length;i++){
  var getAddress = $scope.xyz(arratJson[i].name);
    }
  $scope.createBody();

 };
 $scope.createBody = function(){
 //some more code here
 };
 $scope.xyz = function(name){
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'rest/address',
            type:'json',
            headers:{'action':'single','name':name},  
            }).success(function(response){
             return response;
            }).error(function(response){

            });
   };
```

so in this it is not waiting to get address instead of it moving down so how to wait finishing for loop and then call different function.
createBody function called before the $scope.xyz() function returns the value how to wait until loop finishes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call An Asynchronous Javascript Function Synchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously)

Comment: here you are calling one function only. Are you calling second function after this?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected due to asynchronous nature of execution. You should use callbacks to avoid this problem.

Comment: Can you suggest me any nice example

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service.
first store all `$http` calls in an array and with `$q.all(array)` you create a promise that is resolved after all `$http` promises have resolved.

e.g:

```
$scope.abc1 = function(){
  var arrayJson = [{'name':'max','age':'12'},{'name':'tax','age':'16'}]
  var promises = [];
  for(var i=0; i<arratJson.length;i++){
    promises.push($scope.xyz(arratJson[i].name));
  }

  $q.all(promises).then($scope.createBody);

};
```

And on the resolve of this new promise you can call your `createBody` function.

For this to work You should also change `success` callback on the `$scope.xyz` to a `then` callback and return the promise.

e.g:

```
$scope.xyz = function(name){
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'rest/address',
    type:'json',
    headers:{'action':'single','name':name},  
  }).then(function(response){
    return response;
  })["catch"](function(response){

  });
};
```

#### UPDATE

If you don't care if all calls succeed, replace:

```
$q.all(promises).then($scope.createBody);
```

With:

```
$q.all(promises)["finally"]($scope.createBody);
```

*PS: Keep in mind that in the `finally` callback you **don't** get the return values of every call, whereas in the `then` an array will be passed as argument in the callback function which holds in every position a return value of each `$http` call.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply let me try this and revert back to you

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to achieve this

1)Use async:false

2)Need to use callback

choose your way and enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. where to mention async: false in my function;

Comment: Hi Mayur, just add async: false, under or before  type:'json',

Comment: Tell me if more help needed

Answer (score 0):

You should how promises works in javascript.

$http is an asynchronous function. You must return $http result in $scope.xyz function and use then, success, error function callbacks.

Example:

```
function xyz() {
   return $http(...);
}

xyz().then(function(data) {
    address = data.data.address; // in your json dto format
})
```

more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

hope this helps!
regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular promises.

Include promise status to self created object with deferred value, that has `valueOf` and `toString` methods. Last two methods allow to use arithmetic, string and comparison operators.

**Object with deferred value:**

```
 var DeferredValue = function(initial){
    var self = this;
    self._value = initial; 
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    self.$promise = deferred.promise;
    self.$resolved = false;
    self.$resolve = function(value){
      deferred.resolve(value);
    }
    self.$promise.then(function(v){
      self._value = v;
      deferred = null;
      self.$resolved = true;
      delete self.$resolve;
      return self.$promise;
    });
  }

  DeferredValue.prototype = {
    constructor: DeferredValue,
    valueOf: function(){
      return this._value
    },
    toString: function(){
      return this._value.toString()
    }
  }
```

Return this object in your ASYNC function, and resolve them after retrieving data:

```
var getValue = function(){
  var value = new DeferredValue();
  $timeout(function(){
    value.$resolve(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
  },1500);
  return value;
}
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/VNsczhbtDseGk6tb2t7K?p=preview)