# asp.net web form calling a asynchronous javascript function synchronously

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asynchronous, synchronization

I know many people will jump on and try to mark this as possible duplicate of 
[Call an asynchronous javascript function synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously), but my requirement is with asp.net web forms. In the button click event which causing as postback, first I wanted to make a call to async javascript function synchronously and get the response from it and then submit the page or continue with post back.

**The js library I am using is third party one which I don't have any control over and won't support async:false**

Is it possible and how ??

A simple google search gives me options like, jQuery Promises, Deferred etc and below links. I just don't know how do I use those with asp.net

https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-make-an-async-function-synchronous and 
https://github.com/abbr/deasync

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **onclientclick** attribute of asp.net button.

Below is an example on how to use it :

```
 <asp:button id="Button1"
   usesubmitbehavior="true"
   text="Open Web site"
   onclientclick="CallAjax()"
   runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: :) it won't work atleast in my scenario. Thanks for response anyway