# Using async In Node Module - How to Return Results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, npm, async.js

I am in the process of writing an internal NPM module for my company so that applications can interact with a hardware device we have, which we already have a library written for communicating with it. The problem is, one method I am trying to write needs to execute asynchronously. I want the function to send a command to read from the device, wait for it to return (the device library handles this), and then I parse the results. What I am hoping for is for other developers to be able to call exports.getResolution() to get the values. Here is a snippet of my file with the relevant parts:

```
var async = require('async');

exports.getResolution = async.series([
    function(callback) {
    board.sendAndReceive(bufferlib.generateBuffer("read", "0x00001220", "0x00000004"), (function(received) {
            var hex = bufferlib.sortReceivedHex(received);
            var status = parseInt('0x' + hex.substring(0, 1), 16);
            var verticalResolution = parseInt('0x' + hex.substring(1, 4), 16);
            var horizontalResolution = parseInt('0x' + hex.substring(5, 9), 16);
            callback(null, {
                'status': status,
                'vertical': verticalResolution,
                'horizontal': horizontalResolution
            });
        }));
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results) {
    status = results[0];
    return results[0];
});

console.log(exports.getResolution);
```

I have tried callback hell, Promises, bluebird, ES6 async functions, and a bunch of other solutions but I just can't figure this one out. My most recent attempt uses the async node module to try and execute the code asynchronously, which works, but now I just need to get exports.getResolution to return the actual value the final callback receives. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to make this work? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to try to make an async call synchronous. What you need to do is register a method that executes when the result is there. Usually those methods are called callbacks, but Promises are a better way of accomplishing waiting for an async result.

```
exports.getResolution = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function receiveHandler(received) {
            var hex = bufferlib.sortReceivedHex(received);
            var status = parseInt('0x' + hex.substring(0, 1), 16);
            var verticalResolution = parseInt('0x' + hex.substring(1, 4), 16);
            var horizontalResolution = parseInt('0x' + hex.substring(5, 9), 16);

            // If status would say something about it's success you could also
            // use reject instead of resolve to indicate failure
            resolve({
                'status': status,
                'vertical': verticalResolution,
                'horizontal': horizontalResolution
            });
        }

        board.sendAndReceive(bufferlib.generateBuffer("read", "0x00001220", "0x00000004"), receiveHandler);
    }
}

// Usage
exports.getResolution().then(function(response) {
  console.log('succesfully received response:', response);
}, function(response) {
  console.log('something went wrong:', response)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be to give your `getResolution` function a callback parameter. This is how it really should be done.

```
exports.getResolution = function(callback) {
    board.sendAndReceive(bufferlib.generateBuffer("read", "0x00001220", "0x00000004"), function(received) {
        var hex = bufferlib.sortReceivedHex(received);
        var status = parseInt('0x' + hex.substring(0, 1), 16);
        var verticalResolution = parseInt('0x' + hex.substring(1, 4), 16);
        var horizontalResolution = parseInt('0x' + hex.substring(5, 9), 16);
        callback(null, {
            'status': status,
            'vertical': verticalResolution,
            'horizontal': horizontalResolution
        });
    });
}


console.log(exports.getResolution(function (err, results) {
    console.log(results);
}));
```

The above way is the *correct* way of doing things in JS. But, if you absolutely need to make getResolution look synchronous, then you might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously). But it seems that you will need to modify some of your `board` functions to allow for polling...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really would like to avoid potential callback hell if possible, but I appreciate the time and thought you put into your response.