# javascript synchronous functions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, phantomjs

I have three functions in javascript code, one that connects to my mongo database, the other creates a child process and passes the value of database into the phantamjs child process, the third one gets the data from phantomjs and processes it.

I want to make these functions synchronous. is there any specific way of doing so?

This is what i want to do

```
function connectdb() {
                  //connects to mongodb and pushes the    
                  //value of emails from database to an array 
                  //also writes the emails into external .txt file
}
function create_child() {
                 //creates a child phantom process using external .js 
                 //phantom file 
                 //gets data from the child process
}
function process_data() { 
                //process the data received from create_child()
}
```

I want these functions to be called synchronously .. connectdb() then create_child() then process_data()

Comment: Check this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33579720/6568620 .

Comment: `I want to make these functions synchronous` - it's very difficult to make asynchronous functions synchronous, if you think why the function is asynchronous, you should realise why you can't just turn it synchronous - has your exhaustive research found synchronous alternatives to these asynchronous functions?

Comment: @MohamedAbbas `make async code look sync` isn't the same as `make these functions synchronous`

Comment: Show us your function codes and your effort on trying to solve the issue. Can I do X questions are not well received in Stack Overflow.

Comment: what value of database you are passing into the childprocess of phantom.js ??

Comment: I've posted my pseudo code... @SteveFest

Comment: That is NOT answer, but the question body. Put your pseudo code in your QUESTION BODY

Comment: @SteveFest do i need to edit my original question?

Comment: Yes. You do edit your question.

Comment: @AshishKumar i am passing emails value from my columns

Answer (score 0):

you can use [javascript generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) to execute your functions synchronously.

Comment: it would really help me to explain if can post your code or pseudo code.

Comment: Just give an example with asynchronous functions. you can use setTimeout() function to demonstrate the uses

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to do this.

Comment: yes. But in resolve he can do the next task and so on. He ask  for to do the task one by one.

Comment: no, he asked to turn asynchronous function (by way of time travel and magic beans) into synchronous function - you perpetuate the common misconception from years ago that promises can make asynchronous code synchronous

Comment: you can use javascript generators.

Comment: No Promise can not make asynch function synchronous. its a better way of handling call back function.