# Run a promise synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

So, I've been trying to run a promise in a sync way through a generator function. I need it this way, because I have to init a particular object before the rest of the dependencies, and the function that initializes all these dependencies has to return a particular app object, but not a promise (because the damn framework utilizes this object in a synchronous way afterwards).

So, the only small async part that I have to make sync is a ping call. Here's how I've made use of the generator:

```
 function initLogger() {
      const pingLogServer = function* (logServerHost) {
        return ping.promise.probe(logServerHost)
          .then((res) => {
            return res;
          });
      };

      const res = yield pingLogServer(logServerHost);

      if (res.alive === true) {
         ... blah blah, do stuff to logger object

      return logger;
  }
```

Nevertheless, I get a syntax error:

```
const res = yield pingLogServer(logServerHost);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

It's the first time I'm implementing generators, and I used some tutorials ([this](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/how-to-generators-node-js-yield-use-cases/) and [this](http://www.tivix.com/blog/making-promises-in-a-synchronous-manner/)), so I might as well be doing it wrong.

I'm on node `v6.11.1`, so I can't use `async/await` (unfortunately). If there are any other suggestions for implementing this - they're most welcome!

P.S. not a duplicate because it's a very narrowed-down problem/solution case, where I'm providing a big part of the solution and just looking for the end help, and I've explained why I can't use other solutions, f.e. `async/await`.

Comment: As far as I understand the documentation of `yield`, it is used _inside_ the generator function to return the generated object.

Comment: I think the one use generator is `pingLogServer` not the `initLogger` right (since only `pingLogServer` use the `function*` syntax)? Then shouldn't the `yield` be put inside of `pingLogServer` instead of in `initLogger`?

Comment: Trying to run async code synchronously is a bad idea. You need to accept that JavaScript is asynchronous in nature.

Comment: Where is `logServerHost` declared?

Comment: Rather than generators, you might want to look into Promise's and async / await.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @samAlvin and @Chris G - I got your point and it works now! I put the `yield` keyword in front of the `ping.promise...` call. You can post an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: i can refer this question to this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously