# How to wait 'for loop next iteration' until FileReader.onload result obtain

Tags: angular, typescript, filereader

How we can handle async methods in loops? I have a problem in an Angular program, I can't handle async methods. I want to wait for async methods.
is there any way to wait for async methods in for loop.

**Here is my code:**

```
msg: string[] = [];  

filePicked() {
    this.msg = [];
    this.msg.push("file picked");
    const file: File = new File([""], "C:\Users\Arun Girivasan\Downloads\about.jpg");

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () {
        this.msg.push("file loaded successfully");
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);


    this.msg.push(i.toString());
}
```

**html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let m of msg">{{m}}</div>
```

**output:**

```
file picked  
0  
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
9  
file loaded successfully  
file loaded successfully  
file loaded successfully  
file loaded successfully  
file loaded successfully  
file loaded successfully  
file loaded successfully  
file loaded successfully  
file loaded successfully
```

**I want output like :**

```
file picked

file loaded successfully  
0  
file loaded successfully  
1  
file loaded successfully  
2  
file loaded successfully  
3  
file loaded successfully  
4  
file loaded successfully  
5  
file loaded successfully  
6  
file loaded successfully  
7  
file loaded successfully  
8  
file loaded successfully  
9
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call An Asynchronous Javascript Function Synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it by recursion
This worked for me:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.filePicked();
  }

  filePicked() {
    this.msg = [];
    this.msg.push("file picked");
    const file: File = new File(["abcd"], "C:\Users\Arun Girivasan\Downloads\about.jpg");
    
    this.customLoop(0, 10, file);
  }
  customLoop(index: number, limit: number, file: File) {
    this.readFileUrl(file, (msg: string) => {
      this.msg.push(msg);
      this.msg.push(index.toString());
      if (index < limit - 1) {
        this.customLoop(++index, limit, file);
      }
    });
  }
  readFileUrl(file: File, callback: (msg: string) => any) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (f) {
      return function (e) {
        callback("file loaded successfully");
      }
    })(file);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to extract the filereader code into another function and return a Promise or Observable.

```
private readFile(file: File): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable(obs => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        obs.next(reader.result as string);
        obs.complete();
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

I prepared a quick example with Observable at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pt3pbv

Answer (score 0):

> it works for me, try ..

```
file64=[];
reader.onloadend =(e) =>{
            
    
              var result = reader.result; 
                  console.log(i+'/'+result)
                  this.file64.push(result)
            };
```