# how I can call promise synchronously

Tags: javascript

calling an Async function synchronously

```
//return Boolean value
function SyncValue(){ 
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(/* asynchronous code execution is successful */) {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
    return promise.then(returnValue =>{ return returnValue});
});
```

call function

```
if(SyncValue()){
   //here do the logic 
}
```

how I can lock the calling for the function to retrieve a value from "syncValue" function

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously

Comment: This is simply not possible. You need to change the way it is called.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `async/await` syntax with IIFE where you wait for your async call to resolve and then use that value.

```js
function asyncCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(5)
    }, 2000)
  });
}

(async function() {
  const result = await asyncCall();
  if (result) console.log(result)
})()
```