# Can we call non-async function from async function?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with calling a non-async function from the function method. Is there any way to do this?

Example:

```
async function myMethod()
{
  console.log('In async method');
  nonasyncmethod(); 
}

function nonasyncmethod()
{
  console.log('In non-async method');
}
```

Comment: If you are talking about *object methods* then you likely need to call the method as `this.nonasyncmethod()`. But that's how methods work in general and has nothing to do with async. If that doesn't solve your problem please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call An Asynchronous Javascript Function Synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously)

Comment: Is your example code have valid syntax ?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen no my question is opposite of that question

Comment: Yes you can call a non-async method from async method. And your javascript function declarations are wrong. Their name should be preceded by the "function" keyword.

Comment: Given your edit, the code will work as it is. Again, if you have problem, then you should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call both asynchronous and synchronous functions from within an `async` function - they do not have to be *all* asynchronous (of course the primary reason for having an `async` function is for asynchronous functions, but they work with synchronous functions as well):

```js
async function myMethod() {
  console.log('In async method');
  nonasyncmethod();
}

function nonasyncmethod() {
  console.log('In non-async method');
}

myMethod();
```