# How to generalize code from a sync and an async class to an abstract class in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, abstract-class

Say I have the following classes:

```
abstract class AbstractFileReader {
  // ???
}

class SyncFileReader extends AbstractFileReader {
  public readFileDecorated(filePath: string): string {
    console.log('Filepath: ');
    console.log(filePath);
    const contents = this.readFileInternal(filePath);
    console.log('Length of file: ');
    console.log(contents.length);
    return contents;
  }
  private readFileInternal(filePath: string): string {
    return fs.readFileSync(filePath, {'encoding': 'utf8'});
  }
}

class AsyncFileReader extends AbstractFileReader {
  // highly redundant code...
  public async readFileDecorated(filePath: string): Promise<string> {
    console.log('Filepath: ');
    console.log(filePath);
    const contents = await this.readFileInternal(filePath);
    console.log('Length of file: ');
    console.log(contents.length);
    return contents;    
  }
  private async readFileInternal(filePath: string): Promise<string> {
    return await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, {'encoding': 'utf8'});
  }
}

const syncFileReader = new SyncFileReader();
const asyncFileReader = new AsyncFileReader();
asyncFileReader.readFileDecorated('./test.txt').then((contents) => {
  console.log(contents);
}).catch((reason) => console.log('abc'));

// The following call should still work without change after the changes in AbstractFileReader.
console.log(syncFileReader.readFileDecorated('./test.txt'));
```

The code in `readFileDecorated` (just a silly example of course) is highly redundant, so I want to put it in a method in `AbstractFileReader` instead. However, the problem is that `readFileDecorated` is sync in `SyncFileReader` but async in `AsyncFileReader`.

The straightforward solution I came up with was to make everything async in `AbstractFileReader`. This would work, but then, the call in the last line had to be changed, which I do not want to do because a `SyncFileReader` should expose only sync syntax.

Another solution was to use `readFileDecoratedPre(filePath)` and `readFileDecoratedPost(contents)` methods that are called before or after (resp.) the call to `readFileInternal`, but this would not be a feasible solution when a method contains several sync/async calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can make synchronous code asynchronous by using Promises. You can create a promise and immediately resolve it.

This way the signatures in your SyncFileReader are the same as in AsyncFileReader.

```
class SyncFileReader extends AbstractFileReader {
  public readFileDecorated(filePath: string): Promise<string> {
    console.log('Filepath: ');
    console.log(filePath);
    const contents = this.readFileInternal(filePath);
    console.log('Length of file: ');
    console.log(contents.length);
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(contents));
  }
  private readFileInternal(filePath: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(fs.readFileSync(filePath, {'encoding': 'utf8'})));
  }
}
```

You could also check if the value returned from a method is a Promise and await it if it is.

```
const promiseContents: string|Promise<string> = this.readFileInternal(filePath);
let contents: string;
if (typeof contents?.then === 'function') {
    contents = await promiseContents
} else {
    contents = promiseContents
}
```

But this is not the nicest solution.

Comment: Thanks, but the last call `console.log(syncFileReader.readFileDecorated('./test.txt'));` would then log the Promise object, not the string. I do not want to change the sync syntax of `SyncFileReader`.

Comment: If you know you'll get a `SyncFileReader` and want to keep it synchronous you should not try to generalize this code, maybe pull common code in functions in a super class or utility file. Making this a general solution and forcing async methods to be sync is really bad practice [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously)

Answer (score 0):

I now went for the following solution:

First, I created a function `handleValue` like this:

```
function handleValue<T>(sync: boolean, valueOrPromise: T | Promise<T>, callback: (t: T) => void): T | Promise<T> {
  if (sync) {
    const value = valueOrPromise as T;
    callback(value);
    return value;
  } else {
    const promise = valueOrPromise as Promise<T>;
    promise.then(callback);
    return promise;
  }  
}
```

Then, I changed the classes as follows (note that I changed the method signatures slightly):

```
abstract class AbstractFileReader {
  protected _readFileDecorated(filePath: string, sync: boolean): string | Promise<string> {
    console.log('Filepath: ');
    console.log(filePath);
    const contentsOrPromise = this._readFileInternal(filePath);
    const callback = (contents: string): void => {
      console.log('Length of file: ');
      console.log(contents.length);
    };
    handleValue(sync, contentsOrPromise, callback);
    return contentsOrPromise;
 }

 protected abstract _readFileInternal(filePath: string): string | Promise<string>;
}

class SyncFileReader extends AbstractFileReader {
  public readFileDecorated(filePath: string): string {
    return this._readFileDecorated(filePath, true) as string;
  }
  protected _readFileInternal(filePath: string): string {
    return fs.readFileSync(filePath, {'encoding': 'utf8'});
  }
}

class AsyncFileReader extends AbstractFileReader {
  public async readFileDecorated(filePath: string): Promise<string> {
    return this._readFileDecorated(filePath, false);
  }
  protected async _readFileInternal(filePath: string): Promise<string> {
    return await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, {'encoding': 'utf8'});
  }
}
```

I admit that this is a bit of cheating because the `callback` function in `_readFileDecorated` is essentially the same idea as `readFileDecoratedPost(contents)`, but at least it is better than the original solution because it has no redundancy anymore.