# How to wait until a callback is finished to return from ES6 Proxy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, emscripten, es6-proxy

I can't use promises because it force the user to convert everything to async functions for sync methods. Is there any way to force the proxy to not to return until the callback complete?

```js
function callbackCase() {
    function saySomething(callback) {
        callback("Stackoverflow");
    }

    console.error = new Proxy(console.error, {
        apply: (target, thisArg, args) => {
            saySomething((result) => {
                return result;
            })
        }
    })

    let test = console.error();

    console.log("From Callback Case", test);
}




function nonCallbackCase() {
    console.errors = new Proxy(console.error, {
        apply: (target, thisArg, args) => {
            return "Stackoverflow";
        }
    })

    let test = console.errors();

    console.log("From Non Callback Case", test);
}


callbackCase()
nonCallbackCase()
```

Comment: No. Why do you think would proxies help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to force the proxy to not to return until the callback complete?

No, there is not.  You can't make an asynchronous operation into a synchronous operation in Javascript.  Anything you try to do (like looping on a flag) will just block the event loop and thus block your asynchronous operation from completing, so you'll be deadlocked.

There are three basic ways to communicate back the results or completion of an asynchronous operation, a callback, a promise or an event.  You will need to use one of those mechanisms.

Said another way, you can't squeeze an asynchronous operation into a synchronous API.  You have to change the API to be an asynchronous API.  Returning a promise that is tied to your asynchronous operation is the modern way to do this in Javascript.  This lets the caller, then use either `.then()` or `await` to monitor completion and the result of the operation.

Comment: what about `Promise.all` does it not would solve the problem?

Comment: @jfriend00 What about generator functions then?  I discovered them just five min ago and it seems they can be paused but one issue is that they return a object with something like {value: "result goes here"} and I need to return the result directly..

Comment: @jeffbRTC - Generator functions don't make an asynchronous operation into a synchronous operation so I don't see how they speak to the question you asked.

Comment: @jfriend00 I said you they can be paused and when async operation complete, resume then return.

Comment: @jeffbRTC - You'd have to show me how you think it applies here because I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @Sysix - `Promise.all()` is just a promise-based solution for tracking multiple asynchronous promise-based operations.  The OP seems to be trying to avoid returning a promise (I'm not sure why) so `Promise.all()` would not help them with that.

Comment: @jeffbRTC Just like `async function`s, generator `function*`s do only pause with cooperation by the caller - they don't pause the whole thread but only the body of the function.

Comment: @Bergi Good to have here. But what if we pause the function body and let the callback to resume the body... I am thinking some sort of loop after resumed.  I'm 99% sure there is way.

Comment: A nested generator function like *function main()  inside Proxy so we bypass the caller thing. The caller would be proxy itself.

Comment: There is this library called coroutines.js and it use frequency based mechsmisim to poll the result. I still need to look deep into this.

Comment: I discovered another thing. Sync XHR to service worker......Interesting...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61190354/14659574

Comment: @jeffbRTC - Yeah, but synchronous XHR from the main thread is a bad thing.  It blocks the entire browser UI.  If this takes more than a second to execute, the user will think your web page is hung.  Your energy here should be put into redesigning the code to use an asynchronous API, not trying to find some "hack with consequences" to work around it.  I'm not going to continue to play this game.  I've offered my advice.

Comment: Well, you've now been researching this for at least half a day.  Why don't you just learn how to program asynchronously (which will be generally useful going forward anyway) and rewrite the caller to use an asynchronous API?  Just return a promise from your function and have the caller use that promise.

Comment: @jfriend00  I know how to program asynchronously. It's not useful when most websites don't use "await" keyword when calling proxied functions. I inject my monkeypatch script on every website I visit.

Comment: I went with synchronous XHR anyway.