# Force mocha to require a return value?

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, chai

Is there are way to force mocha to require a return value from tests? When testing Promises i do it like:

```js
it("some test", () => {
  return someFunctionThatReturnsAPromise()
    .then(result => {
      assert.ok(result)
      // ...
    })
})
```

and everything passes/fails as it should whether or not the Promise is resolved or rejected. But if I forget to the "return" (which I do A LOT), then the test passes even if the Promise is rejected.

NOTE: I'm using npm-current mocha with chai-assert.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your test into an [async test](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code):

```js
it("some test", async () => {
  asset.ok(await someFunctionThatReturnsAPromise())
})
```

Comment: Yea I thought of that, and that is how my tests were originally written, but the non-async/await wait seems a lot cleaner. I'd rather not riddle all tests with async/awaits all over the place.

Comment: If you don't want to use async tests, it will be nearly impossible, and your question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by setting mocha's *asyncOnly* option to *true* (https://mochajs.org/api/mocha).

The unfortunate side effect of this is that ALL tests now must return a Promise (or call done()). That is preferable to me though... So far only one of my test modules (*.test.js) wasn't doing this, but I can just *return Promise.resolve()* from those for now, until I figure out how to change mocha.asyncOnly on a per-module basis.