# Puppeteer: Async initialization steps

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to have the two lines in my `initialize` method be run once so I can call other methods after `this.browser` and `this.page` are set. I can't do this in the constructor as they're async.

When I run this code I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'goto' of undefined`.

How can I set these variables so they can be used in other methods?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

class Bot {
    constructor() {}

    async initialize() {
        this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        this.page = await this.browser.newPage();
    }

    async login() {
        await this.page.goto('https://reddit.com/login/', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    }

    ...

}

const bot = new Bot();
bot.initialize();
bot.login();
```

Comment: You need to wait the initialize execution `const bot = new Bot();
bot.initialize().then(()=>bot.login());`

Comment: Or `await` the promises. You can't syncify async code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call An Asynchronous Javascript Function Synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously)