# Markdown syntax highlighting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, syntax-highlighting, markdown

I am trying to get the [rainbow](https://github.com/ccampbell/rainbow) syntax highlighting library to work with the [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) markdown rendering engine. The `marked` documentation states that a syntax highlighter is supported through the following configuration option:

```
marked.setOptions({
  highlight: function(code, lang) {
    return highlighter.javascript(code);
  }
});
```

The `rainbow` [source code](https://github.com/ccampbell/rainbow/blob/master/js/rainbow.js#L740) indicates that passing in a string to highlight is supported via the following syntax:

```
Rainbow.color(code, lang, success);
```

I'm a bit at a loss as to how to put the two together. Specifically, `success` is a callback that will be called asynchronously, and I can't simply return the value from the `Rainbow.color` code inside the `highlight` callback. How would this be accomplished?

Comment: You need something like http://www.usbfirewire.com/uconverters.html but for CPS transformations...

Comment: Cool. Does that have anything to do with `$.Deferred`?

Comment: I don't think so. The problem is that marked seems to require a synchronous syntax highlighter and there's no way to transform an asynchronous one like rainbow in a synchronous one (that's why for example many `node.js` lib functions provide also a "...Synch" version... there's no way to build one from Javascript). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6842256/320726

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Author of marked here. I addressed this a while ago on the issue tracker: https://github.com/chjj/marked/issues/47

It's more than possible to use an asynchronous highlighter with marked. You'll just have to iterate over the tokens the lexer spits out.

Example here: https://github.com/chjj/marked/issues/47#issuecomment-5297067 (Keep in mind this is an example. You'll have to modify it a bit.)

I might just implement this natively in marked using the method in the link above. It will be a performance hit to the people using async highlighters, but if you need an async highlighter, that means the highlighter is doing some kind of IO and you're already taking a performance hit.

Answer (score 5):

You could try using another highlighting library, such as [highlight.js](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js) - It has synchronous highlighting methods (`hljs.highlight(lang, code).value` and `hljs.highlightAuto(code).value`) that you can use in the browser like this:

```
marked.setOptions({
  highlight: function(code) {
    return hljs.highlightAuto(code).value;
  }
});
```

[Here's a working JsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/7bsouk2d/1/)

Comment: Your sample is not working. The JsFiddle is missing the libraries for marked & Co.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no way to solve the problem.

`marked` seems to require a **synchronous** syntax highlighter, and `rainbow` is an **asynchronous** syntax highlighter.

In Javascript there's no way to convert the latter to the former.

This is for example the reason why in `node.js` for many library functions there are both a synchronous and an asynchronous version. There's no way in Javascript to build a synchronous one given only the asynchronous one because you cannot create a "nested event loop" (in some cases the opposite conversion instead can be done using web workers).

May be it's not difficult to add the synchronous version to `rainbow` (e.g. by providing beforehand the external resources that it is probably loading asynchronously).

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Looks like it's already been [proposed](https://github.com/ccampbell/rainbow/issues/43), but the [pull request](https://github.com/ccampbell/rainbow/pull/79) has been forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

Not the perfect solution, but until the synchronous API has been merged into rainbow.js I solved it with the code below:

```
// ... after marked() has converted the markdown to html 
// (the highlight option of marked should be unchanged!)

// find all <code> elements and go through each
$('body')
     .find('code')
     .each(function() {
            var $code = $(this),
                cls = $code.attr('class'),
                language;

            // no language information at all
            if(typeof cls === 'undefined') {
                return;
            }

            // actually we should also check if a valid "lang-" class 
            // (which is by default set through marked) is given
            language = cls.split('-')[1];

            // add the data-language to the <code> element
            $code.data('language', language);
        });

// let the rainbows shine
Rainbow.color();
```

This runs client side and uses jQuery.