# How to access a variable in all the function and conditions in asynchronous function node js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I want to access k and error value inside and outside a function.
I had initialized the value for k as 0 and error as an empty string. But the `console.log("executed")` is printed.

```
var  k = 0;
var error = "";

const { teamname, event_name, inputcount, name, roll } = req.body;
function check1(teamname, event_name, callback) {
    Register.find({ teamname: teamname, eventname: event_name }, (err, docs) => {
        callback(docs.length)
    });
}
check1(teamname, event_name, function (e) {
    if (e != 0) {
        console.log("executed");
        k = 1
    }
});
console.log(k) // 0
console.log(error) // undefined
```

Comment: define k and error as global variable, if you are using express, you can also use app.locals to set variable as gobal

Comment: Can you please post some sample code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452123/how-to-create-global-variables-accessible-in-all-views-using-express-node-js/45326030

Comment: sir, I tried but same result can you please solution post with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare **global variables** using NodeJS global object. But in your case, you want the k to be 1, but it's 0. because NodeJS is **asynchronous**, you should console.log(k) inside the callback.

When you run this program, the console.log(k) and console.log(error) executes before the `check1` function returns the value to the callback. That's asynchronous process. so you are getting k as 0. In order to solve it, you should console.log inside the callback

```
var k = 0;
var error = "error";

const { teamname, event_name, inputcount, name, roll } = req.body;
function check1(teamname, event_name, callback) {
        Register.find({ teamname: teamname, eventname: event_name }, (err, docs) => {
            callback(docs.length)
        });
    }
    check1(teamname, event_name, function (e) {
       if (e != 0) {
            console.log("executed");
            k = 1
       }
       console.log(k) // prints 0 or 1
       console.log(error) // prints "error"
    });
```

https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/

Comment: In my code 10 th line I had updated the value `k` as `1`, but still the value is printed as `0`.sure the part is executed and in console `executed` line is also printed but the k value is not updating

Comment: try again now i have changed the global object to var variable

Comment: I had seen your updated post, is there is any possibility to change the asynchronous as synchronous

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884418/how-can-i-make-this-call-to-request-in-nodejs-synchronous this answer might help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189290/discussion-between-rajendran-bala-and-bear-nithi).