# How to implement synchronized http request in Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: azure, httprequest

I'm talking about server side table scripts.

I need to implement function to make synchronized http request in Azure Mobile Services - without callbacks.

Something like that:

```
var data1 = httpRequest(url1);
var data2 = httpRequest(url2);
var data3 = httpRequest(url3);
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible here are some options:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048504/synchronous-request-in-nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

```
var request = require('request')

request({ uri: 'http://api.com/1' }, function(err, response, body){
    // use body
    request({ uri: 'http://api.com/2' }, function(err, response, body){
        // use body
        request({ uri: 'http://api.com/3' }, function(err, response, body){
            // use body
        })
    })
})
```

more options in here:
[Synchronous request in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048504/synchronous-request-in-nodejs)

Comment: sorry, I've edited the answer. Check the link I post on the answer. There's more options in there.