# How to handle the asynchronous transaction in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise

My application is built on `Nodejs` + `Mongodb` + `amqp`. The core module is receiving the the message from `amqp`, then wrap it into the corresponding message transaction. In the message transaction, save the message information into `mongodb` and some other logic.

```
function messageReceiverCallback(msg) {
  try {
    messageHandler(decode(msg));
  } catch (ex) {
  } 
}

function messageHandler(msg) {
  function defaultTransaction() {
  }
  var dispatch = {
    'default': defaultTransaction
  }

  dispatch[MSG.TYPE1] = Msg1Transaction;
  // other message transaction here

  return (dispatch[msg.type] || dispatch['default'])(msg);
}

function Msg1Transaction(msg) {
   // some mongodb operation here...
}
```

However, when there are several same type messages with different message field value in the queue of `amqp`, then the `messageReceiverCallback` will be called, and the `Msg1Transaction` also be invoked multiple times. As a result, the data saved in the `mongodb` will be incorrect, because of the **asynchronous** operation on `mongodb` which I have ignored. **How can I handle it in this case??**

I have one idea, add one new transaction queue wrapped with `Promise` maybe. So the transaction can be processed asynchronously. But I do not how to implement it? could one can help me or some other better solution to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `amqp`, but if I understood your problem you want the `messageHandler` to return when the `mongo` operation finishes. In this case the correct logic would be:

```
function messageReceiverCallback(msg) {
   try {
     messageHandler(decode(msg));
    } catch (ex) { ... } 
}

function messageHandler(msg) {
   Msg1Transaction(msg, callbackAfterTransaction);
}

function callbackAfterTransaction(data){
   // update transaction info
}

function Msg1Transaction(msg, callback) {
 // some mongodb operation here...
 Collection.find ({}, 
    function(err, data)
    {
       ...
       callback(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there are three `Msg1` at the same time, then three `Msg1Transaction` are created. I want to those three transaction processed  asynchronously in chain, such as `Promise(Msg1Transaction).then(Msg1Transaction).then(Msg1Transaction)`, How should I do?

Comment: I am not sure you grasp the idea of asynchrony. So if you want to process events asynchronously then you have **no control** over the order of execution. If you want to process events synchronously then you can do that as well by using some third party library (take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048504/synchronous-request-in-nodejs)).