# Break request function if previous result was wrong

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to write some parser on node. I can't understand something here.
I need to stop requesting next pages if previous result was wrong.
My current code is something like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var links = ['http://link1','http://link2','http://link3'];

for(l in links) {
var link = links[l];
request(link, function(err, page) {
    if(err) throw err;

    $ = cheerio.load(page.body);
    if($('a').length < 2) {
        // here i need to stop requesting next url(s) from links array        somehow!
        // (if this is the case of link1 then link2 and link3 will not  request)
    } else {
        // do something...
    }
    $.html();
});
}
```

Comment: You're requesting all links **in parallel**. I recommend taking a look at the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library and use `async.eachSeries`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronous request in nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048504/synchronous-request-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js is an asynchronous language, so you can't stop it in native javascript like `break;`, so you probably try using the `async` [module](https://github.com/caolan/async) like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var links = ['http://link1', 'http://link2', 'http://link3'];
var async = require('async');

async.eachSeries(links, function(link, callback) {
    request(link, function(err, page) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        $ = cheerio.load(page.body);
        if ($('a').length < 2) {
            // here i need to stop requesting next url(s) from links array        somehow!
            // (if this is the case of link1 then link2 and link3 will not  request)
            callback(err);
            return;
        } else {
            // do something...
        }
        $.html();
        callback();
    });
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        //do something id some of the links throws err
        return;
    }
    //do womething if every request was success
});
```

The above code will run a function for each element in the array(links), if one of the links will call `callback` with error, it will immidiately stop the iteration and will call the callback function with the error. Otherwise if all of the elements will call `callback` without any params, the callback function will be called without any params.

Please look at `async` docs to see other options that might help you in other ways.