# How to make 'http requests' synchronous in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm trying to execute 3 'http requests'. The problem is, because of the nature of asynchronous mode, it doesn't execute in order. All requests are to internal apis. Here's the sample code :-

```
setInterval(function () {
  // First request
  request({}, function (error, response, body) {
   // Second request
   request({}, function (error, response, body) {
    // Third request
    request({}, function (error, response, body) {
    })
   })
  })
},1000);
```

What i'm trying to achieve is get data based on one condition (`First request`), update data (`Second request`) and send sms and emails (`Third request`). Because of the asynchronous nature, code is getting repeated many times.
I'm using setInterval so the code will always run every second

Comment: Those three requests **should** occur in order. You only call one when the previous one has a response and the callback fires.

Comment: See duplicate question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048504/synchronous-request-in-nodejs

Comment: Yeah this looks correct to me as well. See my answer on using Promises though.

Comment: You can't make them synchronous, but you can make them look synchronous (syntactically) . Take a look at `co` library and `Promise` (part of ES6 standard )

Answer (score 5):

You can easily sequence requests using `Promises`

```
// Load Dependencies: 
var Promise = require('promise');
var request = require('request');

// Begin Execution:
main();

function main() {
  getData()                //Executes 1st
   .then(updateData)       //Whatever is 'fulfilled' in the previous method, gets passed to this function updateData
   .then(sendNotification) //Whatever is fulfilled in the previoud method, gets passed to this function sendNotification.
   .catch(function(err) {
     console.log('If reject is called, this will catch it - ' +err);
   });
}

// Request #1:
function getData() {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    request({}, function(err, res, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject('Error making request - ' +err);
      } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        reject('Invalid API response - ' +body);
      } else {
        fulfill(body);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Request #2:
function updateData(data) {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    request({}, function(err, res, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject('Error making request - ' +err);
      } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        reject('Invalid API response - ' +body);
      } else {
        fulfill(body);
      }
    });
  });
}


// Request #3
function sendNotification(phoneNumber, email) {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    request({}, function(err, res, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject('Error making request - ' +err);
      } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        reject('Invalid API response - ' +body);
      } else {
        fulfill(body);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

So basically just wrap your async functions with `return new Promise`, to *return* the ready data via `fulfill` or `reject`. In `function main()`, you can see how the sequence for this order has been easily defined.

Comment: That won't solve the problem if the problem is a `setInterval` that causes the first request to occur repeatedly before the third has completed.

Comment: But why is `setInterval` being used in the first place? Only because of a lack of a proper understanding is why I thought.

Comment: @love I would like to run the entire process every one second

Comment: @sandeshps Can you just wrap `main()` in setInterval then? Or do you only want it to repeat once the previous three have finished?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to title: You can't make them synchronous. But you can sequence them.

You likely should replace the `setInterval` with a `setTimeout` and then issue another `setTimeout` after the third request completes. Otherwise the `setInterval` will cause the first request re-issued before the third request has an opportunity to complete. Which is likely the issue.

Comment: I would also like to run the entire process every second.

Comment: @sandeshps But you also want it to complete all three requests before issuing the first one again