# Synchronously call a REST API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, npm, synchronization

I am new to JavaScript and the npm world. I try to upload some data to my REST service via a REST post call. These data I fetch from a csv file. So far so good. On each fetched line I convert the data (for my needs) and call the REST API for uploading those. Since I have many line (approx. 700) the API gets called quite often consecutively. After some calls (guess 500 or so) I get an Socket error

```
events.js:136
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:3000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:999:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1020:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1207:14)
```

I guess this is because I call the REST API to often. What I don't understand is: 
How should I make the call synchronously in order to avoid so many connections? 
Or should't I? 
What would be the proper solution in JS for this?

I have tried with Promises and so on but all this didn't helped but moved the issue some function calls priorly...

This is my code:

```
readCsv()

function readCsv() {
    var csvFile = csvFiles.pop()
    if (csvFile) {
        csv({ delimiter: ";" }).fromFile(csvFile).on('json', async (csvRow) => {
            if (/.*\(NX\)|.*\(NI\)|.*\(NA\)|.*\(WE\)|.*\(RA\)|.*\(MX\)/.test(csvRow["Produkt"])) {
                var data = await addCallLog(
                    csvRow["Datum"],
                    csvRow["Zeit"],
                    csvRow["Menge-Zeit"],
                    csvRow["Zielrufnummer"],
                    csvRow["Produkt"]);
            }
        }).on('done', (error) => {
            //console.log('end')
            readCsv()
        })
    } else {

    }
}

function addCallLog(date, time, duration, number, product) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        args.data = { number: number, name: "", timestamp: getTimestamp(date, time), duration: getDuration(duration), type: "OUTGOING" }
        client.methods.addCallLog(args, (data, response) => {
            // client.methods.getCallLog((data, response) => {
            //     console.log(data)
            // })
            //console.log("addCallLog resolve")
            resolve(data)
        })
    })
}
```

As you can see I had the same issue with reading more than one csv files in parallel. I solved this by calling recursively the readCsv function and pop the next file after the other when the file read was done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make 'http requests' synchronous in Node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085510/how-to-make-http-requests-synchronous-in-node-js)

Comment: A problem here is that `await addCallLog()` won't keep the next `json` events from being generated so you will end with a zillion requests in flight at the same time and apparently you have so many that you run out of resources.

Comment: One possibility here is to collect all the json data into an array and then use a `for` loop to iterate the array where your `await addCallLog()` will work to serialize the requests.

Comment: What csv module are you using?

Comment: I was using csvtojson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call things synchronously.  But, you can sequence the async REST calls which is what I presume you mean.

A problem here is that `await addCallLog()` won't keep the next `json` events from being generated so you will end with a zillion requests in flight at the same time and apparently you have so many that you run out of resources.

One way around that is to collect the rows you want into an array and then use a regular `for` loop to iterate that array and you can use `await` sucessfully in the `for` loop.  Here's what that would look like:

```
readCsv()

function readCsv() {
    var csvFile = csvFiles.pop()
    if (csvFile) {
        let rows = [];
        csv({ delimiter: ";" }).fromFile(csvFile).on('json', (csvRow) => {
            if (/.*\(NX\)|.*\(NI\)|.*\(NA\)|.*\(WE\)|.*\(RA\)|.*\(MX\)/.test(csvRow["Produkt"])) {
                rows.push(csvRow);
            }
        }).on('done', async (error) => {
            for (let csvRow of rows) {
                var data = await addCallLog(
                    csvRow["Datum"],
                    csvRow["Zeit"],
                    csvRow["Menge-Zeit"],
                    csvRow["Zielrufnummer"],
                    csvRow["Produkt"]
                );
            }
            readCsv();
        })
    } else {

    }
}

function addCallLog(date, time, duration, number, product) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        args.data = { number: number, name: "", timestamp: getTimestamp(date, time), duration: getDuration(duration), type: "OUTGOING" }
        client.methods.addCallLog(args, (data, response) => {
            // client.methods.getCallLog((data, response) => {
            //     console.log(data)
            // })
            //console.log("addCallLog resolve")
            resolve(data)
        })
    })
}
```

Your coding appears to be missing error handling.  The `client.methods.addCallLog()` needs a way to communicate back an error.

You probably also need a `error` event handler for the csv iterator.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Can't improve my answer if you don't at least comment.

Comment: That solved my problem! Many thanks. Using the buffer was the hint I was the relevant one for me. I have changed my code also in terms of not using await but the "then" callback of the promise. Now its working like a charm.

Btw. Actually I didn't vote down. At least I voted finally up :)

Comment: @burix - Glad your problem is fixed, but I don't know what you mean by "switched to .then()` because it's the `await` inside the `for` loop that makes things run one at a time to prevent running too many requests at a time.

Comment: I used the then function callback of Promises instead of async/await. It is now like a recursive call. But the most important part anyway was to introduce a buffer where I first filled that with data and afterwards. I post my final solution in an answer below...

Answer (score 0):

After filling the buffer in a prev. function I check that buffer for data and upload those one by one using the "then" callback of the promise

```
var callLogBuffer = []

checkForUpload()

function checkForUpload() {
    console.log("checkForUpload")
    if (callLogBuffer.length > 0) {
        addCallLog(callLogBuffer.pop()).then((data) => {
            checkForUpload()
        })
    }
}


function addCallLog(callLog) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        args.data = { number: callLog.number, name: "", timestamp: getTimestamp(callLog.date, callLog.time), duration: getDuration(callLog.duration), type: "OUTGOING" }
        client.methods.addCallLog(args, (data, response) => {
            // client.methods.getCallLog((data, response) => {
            //     console.log(data)
            // })
            //console.log("addCallLog resolve")
            resolve(data)
        })
    })
}
```